# Prevent Meteor reactivity for specific dom element using meteor jade?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to prevent reactivity for one specific DOM element, not the whole template.

I am using meteor-jade

I read about constant and isolate tags for handlebars, in which you nest your code to prevent reactivity. Ive tried:

```
constant
  #full-editor !{researchThread.draftHTML}

isolate 
  #full-editor !{researchThread.draftHTML}
```

and both bring up errors as tags not recognized.

How can I prevent reactivity for this one specigic DOM element in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `reactive` as false if you are finding the data from a collection. Take a look at [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#find)

#### Updated

You pass the `reactive: false` to your find function

```
data = YourCollection.findOne({}, {reactive: false})
```

Then this data wouldn't be reactive

Comment: This stops reactivity for all the data returned to the template though. I just want to stop reactivity for one specific DOM element, or one specific data value from the returned data.

Comment: @nearpoint Author of `meteor-jade` here, is what you are trying to do possible with the spacebars syntax? If not, it's not possible with jade syntax either.